# Get different values with method get from a dropdown menu

Tags: php, forms

How can i get different values with $_GET

the problem is that i want to include different scripts of different options

code:

```
 <Select NAME="offer">
 <Option VALUE="status">Status</option>
 <Option VALUE="company">Advertisers</option>
 <Option VALUE="category">Categories</option>
 <Option VALUE="country">Countries</option>
 <Option VALUE="default_payout">Payouts</option>
 </Select>

<?php if(isset($_GET['offer'])== status){ 
               include_once 'include/offer.php'; 
               include_once 'include/offer_tabel.php'; 
      }

      if(isset($_GET['offer']) == 'company'){
                include_once 'include/advertiser.php';
                include_once 'include/advertiser_tabel.php';

}
?>
```

Wat am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this `if(isset($_GET['offer'])== status` to

```
if(isset($_GET['offer']) &&  $_GET['offer'] == 'status')
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong if condition. Use This:

```
if(isset($_GET['offer']) && $_GET['offer'] == 'status')
```

Same for company

```
if(isset($_GET['offer']) && $_GET['offer'] == 'company')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going wrong at :

```
if(isset($_GET['offer'])== status){
```

`isset()` function returns a `bool` value : http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Good way do write your script is :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['offer'])){
        switch(strtolower(trim($_GET['offer']))){
            case 'status':
                // include your files for status offer
            break;

            case 'company':
                // include your files for company offer
            break;

            default:
                //Some default action
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        //No offer selected
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you cannot use `isset()` to compare with other string. Because this function will return **boolean** value only. Change this to,

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['offer']) && ($_GET['offer'] == 'status')){ 
               include_once 'include/offer.php'; 
               include_once 'include/offer_tabel.php'; 
      }

      if(isset($_GET['offer']) && ($_GET['offer'] == 'company')){
                include_once 'include/advertiser.php';
                include_once 'include/advertiser_tabel.php';

       }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, be sure that your form's method is `get` and not `post`; otherwise, you would need to test the value of `$_POST['offer']`.